# Add <!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.044/cXML.dtd"> via XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to add  at the starting of the xml doc.

desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.044/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="1622098213085.433369813.000000243@TzcfvgHhQOcUqW3reWym5GQWUB4=" timestamp="2021-05-26T23:50:13-07:00" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Response>
        <Status code="200" text="OK"/>
    </Response>
</cXML>
```

I have below XSLT, not sure how to add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <cXML version="{/cXML/@version}" payloadID="{/cXML/@payloadID}" timestamp="{/cXML/@timestamp}"
              signatureVersion="{/cXML/@signatureVersion}">
          <Response Id="{/cXML/Response/@Id}">
            <Status code="{/cXML/Response/Status/@code}" text="{/cXML/Response/Status/@text}"/>
          </Response>
        </cXML>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried below and it does not work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">

<xsl:output doctype-system="http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.044/cXML.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image: XSLT test]

Its working in other XSLT test tool, so the XSLT is good.

[image]

Comment: As an aside, that XSLT is odd. What exactly are you trying to do in that XSLT? There is an easier way to copy structure and the attributes than hard-coding (especially for those attributes).

Comment: That website has an issue parsing the input XML with the DTD. Try another website. https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`xsl:output`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#element-output) with `doctype-system`:

```
<xsl:output doctype-system="http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.044/cXML.dtd"/>
```

Comment: I tried its not working, can you pl advice whats wrong with the XSLT

Comment: You aren't seeing `<!DOCTYPE cXML
  SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.044/cXML.dtd">` in your output?

Comment: I have used the XSLT as mentioned in the question asked, I try to run the XSLT and it faults.

Comment: It works for me. What XSLT engine are you using, and maybe you need to enable DTD flags? For security reasons, resolving DTD is sometimes disallowed by default and you have to enable.

Comment: If you are getting an error, post the error in the question as well. The issue could be parsing the XML with the DTD. It would be helpful to see the error message.